# Ubuntu 14.10 taking a long time to boot

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.10

So, this has only started happening about a week back for no apparent reason. Ubuntu takes almost 4-5 minutes stuck at the purple Ubuntu screen for no apparent reason. Furthermore the GRUB 10-second countdown also stops when Ubuntu takes this long to boot.

This was never a problem previously and I usually got 20-30 second boot times. The machine in question dual-boots Windows 7 with a Core-i5 3230M and 4 GB of RAM.

I also ran dmesg to get this: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=CAUtznex)

I noted a very large time delta from 12 -> 63 -> 125. What is the cause for this and how can I fix it?